# Css for list is not working with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a table for my website. I am using the list method to create the table with the help of CSS. The problem is that it's not working properly when Bootstrap CDN applied. When I remove bootstrap CDN it's working fine. But I can't eliminate bootstrap because it's required for some other sections.

**With BS4**
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xn9g.jpg)

**Without BS4**
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUUkF.jpg)

```css
.wrapper-usd {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto 100px auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

/* lists */
.row-usd ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row-usd ul li {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  .row-usd ul li {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .row-usd ul li {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

.title-usd ul li {
  padding: 15px 13px;
}

.row-usd ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

/* rows */
.row-usd {
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.title-usd {
  padding: 25px 0 5px 0;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper-usd">
    <main class="row-usd title-usd">
      <ul>
        <li>Name</li>
        <li>Amount</li>
        <li>Count</li>
        <li>Max</li>
        <li>Time</li>
      </ul>
    </main>
      <article class="row-usd">
        <ul>
          <li>Harikumar jyadev</li>
          <li>$50</li>
          <li>12</li>
          <li>48</li>
          <li>2:00ET</li>
        </ul>
      </article>
      <article class="row-usd">
        <ul>
          <li>Harikumar jyadev</li>
          <li>$50</li>
          <li>12</li>
          <li>48</li>
          <li>2:00ET</li>
        </ul>
      </article>
  </section>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working correctly?

Comment: Can you tell us before and after scenario with the help of snippet

Comment: Okay I'll add the screenshot

Comment: I added 2 screenshots before and after applying BS4. Can you please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css code:

```
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Perfect !! 
Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try import your custom css file after importing bootstrap? Something like

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Not working. I am using inline CSS for custom css. I tried your method anyway but not working.

Comment: Show me your full html file

Answer (score 0):

> I am using the list method to create the table with the help of CSS

Using the table tag seems wiser, and [it is how Bootstrap manage tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/).